# Handle EF Core migrations with container orchestration

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, entity-framework-core, dockerfile

I am building a vanilla web app with ASP.Net Core, Entity Framework Core and PostgreSQL, which I want to deploy using a container orchestrator on top of Docker (whether Docker Swarm or Kubernetes).

I am wondering how to integrate my database migrations inside the deployment process.

My current `Dockerfile` (I am using multi-stage build) is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine as builder
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
COPY --from=builder /app/publish /app/
WORKDIR /app
CMD dotnet MyApp.dll
```

My `docker-compose.yml` (which I want to use via the `docker stack` command, so it excludes the use of `build` option):

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        image: edouardberthe/myapp
        ports:
            - 80:80
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:latest
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
            - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: myapp_user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myapp_pass
            POSTGRES_DB: myapp_db
volumes:
    data:
```

Now I want to launch my migrations (generated by Entity Framework core via `dotnet ef migrations add`) on each deployment.

During the development process, I use `dotnet ef database update`.
However, I cannot do that because it means I would need the .Net Core SDK during runtime (and furthermore I have seen it is considered a bad practice from SO posts and Microsoft docs).

I have seen from [this discussion on github](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/issues/89#issuecomment-347256632) that it is a better practice to use `dotnet ef migrations script --idempotent`, which generates a plain-SQL migration file, at build time, and then running this script at runtime. But (as said in the post) "the only problem is that I will also need a commandline client for the used database on the runtime image."

If I follow this process, my Dockerfile would become something (much bigger and more complex) like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine as builder
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o publish \
    && dotnet ef migrations script --output publish/migrate.sql --idempotent 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
COPY --from=builder /app/publish /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man7 \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get clean
CMD psql -f migrate.sql && dotnet MyApp.dll
```

(the two `mkdir` lines are from [this post](https://github.com/dalibo/temboard/issues/211#issuecomment-342205157) and [this fix](https://github.com/dalibo/temboard/commit/ff98d6740ae11345658508b02052294d6cffd448))
Apart from the large complexity it adds, the last CMD line doesn't work, because I don't have access to the database!
I do know what the db name, user and password will be (even if I don't think it is such a good idea to put it in the Dockerfile), but I don't know yet what the `host` will be.

Isn't there a better way to handle migrations in such a setup?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a job for orchestration, or even containers, for that matter. Migrating a database schema should be part of your CI/CD pipeline. Deploying the final product to Kubernetes/Swarm would be the last step of such a pipeline.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. But even if I am using a CI/CD pipeline, as you said there is a (last) moment where I do need to deploy on K8s/Swarm. At this moment, my production database do have to be updated, so the migrations do have to be launch. Could you elaborate a bit what you meant please?

Comment: Assuming you're running the database in a container, the actual data files are external to that, and can be modified before actual deployment of the new container, if there even is a new container. The point is that it's external to the actual cluster deployment. There's various CI/CD tools to handle DB migrations. You just need to do some research and pick one.

Comment: Ok, but then what is the point of having a compose file? I thought docker Swarm **was** a Continuous Deployment tool.

Comment: ..Deployment tool. Very basically, isn't  the command "docker stack deploy -c compose.file" supposed to handle the whole deployment process?

Comment: No. Not at all. Swarm or other orchestrators simply manage the cluster. As part of that functionality, they do "deploy" containers, in a sense, but that's not the same as *deployment*. Your deployment is the orchestrator config/new container images. The orchestrator, then, just does what it does and spins up/down containers to match the config.

Comment: Ok, thanks again for this explanation then! Could you post an answer so that I mark it as solving my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if this is best practice, but you can trigger schema upgrade from your C# code. You must add following code to Configure method at Startup.cs:

```cs
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices
    .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
    .CreateScope())
{
    using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<EasyAdminContext>())
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

This way the database will be updated when the application starts

Comment: This will cause issues when running with multiple containers

Comment: What kind of issues do you mean? I think the first container started will update schema, others won't start updating because of the __EFMigrationsHistory table in the DB.

Comment: There is no locking/transaction around the __EFMigrationsHistory table, so 2 containers can try to execute the same migration simultaneously. Which tends to fail :)

Comment: Great, they left it here. I still don't know what to do.

Comment: @dystopiandev, sorry for this :) The answer is really depend on your setup. If you have only one replica of your app, then you can choose the option I proposed.

Comment: However, in case with multiple containers you can have an orchestrator. Kubernetes is a good option for this: statefulset will start pods one by one. First pod will execute migration process; others will start normally, without starting migration.
In case if you have docker-compose as an orchestrator, the easiest way for you - provide scale flag for up command: scale to 1 on startup, after migration scale service numbers to previous value.
And if you want your application to be clustered, app architecture should provide different techniques for this, such a db locks, leader/follower, etc.